# Combine 2 selects into 1 select using KnockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js

I have 2 select elements on my web page. Is there a way to combine the select options from both select elements into 1 select element using KnockoutJS?

**Given: (2 selects)**

```
<select id="select1">
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
</select>


<select id="select2">
    <option>Three</option>
    <option>Four</option>
</select>
```

**Desired Result:**

```
<select id="select1">
    <option>Select 1</option> //if possible
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
    <option>Select 2</option> //if possible
    <option>Three</option>
    <option>Four</option>
</select>
```

Comment: i don't understand. you want [a,b,c] in both lists?

Comment: I updated original post with illustration

Comment: Why exactly do you need KnockoutJS for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript:

```
var select1 = $('#select1'),
    select2 = $('#select2'),

    // create an array to bind
    options = ko.observableArray();

// this value doesn't exist in the dom
options.push('Select 1');

// add the text of all children to the array
select1.children().forEach(function(i, el) {
    options.push(el.innerText);
});

// this value doesn't exist in the dom
options.push('Select 2');

// add the text of all children to the array
select2.children().forEach(function(i, el) {
    options.push(el.innerText); 
});

// bind an options with the options property 
//  set to the options array to the dom
ko.applyBindings({ options: options });
```

In HTML:

```
<select data-bind="options: options"></select>
```